# How to show all running processes on macOS/OS X?

Tags: macos

How do I see a list of all running processes/tasks on macOS/OS X?

Answer (score 74):

Inside Terminal, you can type `ps aux`

[image]

Terminal is available under the utilities folder in the App folder.

Comment: Better yet, you can run `pgrep -lf .` to get all running processes with their PIDs and Names. Very useful if you want to kill a process as part of a script with `pkill -x "name"`

Answer (score 45):

Applications / Utilities > Activity Monitor

[image]

Comment: How do I enable it to show ALL Processes? I'm an admin user but can only see my process

Comment: @MichaelBrown - View menu.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `top -o mem` inside terminal, to see running processes

Answer (score 8):

You can use

`top -o cpu`

or

`top -o rsize`

or

`ps aux`

Answer (score 7):

The app /Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor is what you're looking for. If you use the command line in Terminal, the `top` command is useful too. In Terminal, type `man top` to see the various options. Activity Monitor shows you a wealth of information about each process.

Answer (score 3):

To see the process names just by themselves with quotes and new lines, try this in Terminal:

```
ps axc | sed "s/.*:..... /\"/" | sed s/$/\"/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try **top -o +state**, it will show all the running processes in the top of the 'top', however, below it will also show the sleeping processes.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: This solution requires `pstree` to be installed from either  ***MacPorts*** (`sudo port install pstree`) or ***Homebrew*** (`brew install pstree`) first.

To understand the ***relationship between processes***, `pstree` is your friend. Without any switches it will show ALL processes.

However, that produces quite some verbose output. To help narrow the search space for the issue, you can use the `-u` switch, to limit output to puke out only your own processes:

`pstree -u YourUserName`

I had high CPU activity and wanted to see what I did that was triggering it, so being able to see how processes were chained (spawned) was more interesting to me.

Anyhoo, hope this helps you narrow to isolate the cause of a system issue quicker.

Comment: Another useful option is `-w` to prevent the output to be truncated to the terminal width.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something in text mode but `ps` and `top` aren't good enough for you then try [`htop`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98266/15312) (installable with `brew install htop`) — it will interactively show the list of proceses (similar to Activity Monitor), as well as allow to do the following:

- filter processes by name with <kbd>/</kbd>
- kill with <kbd>k</kbd>
- inspect a process with `lsof` with <kbd>L</kbd>
- show the process tree hierarchy with <kbd>t</kbd>
- sort by CPU, state, priority, memory, etc with <kbd>F6</kbd>
- display CPU load per each core

Answer (score -3):

Okay, look what I found:

You can use 
 - Dock
 - Launch Menu (Just press Command + Option + ESC)
 - Install special app for that (e.g. Activity Monitor)
 - Look using terminal
 - Or use console commands

and that is not the full list! I founded all these methods here: https://osxtips.net/view-processes-mac/

Ofc, you can watch by yourself for more using google, bing, etc. C:

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I’m sure you’ll find this site has a lot to offer. Check out [How do I write a good answer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on tips. - From Review