# Is it possible to list running processes that are not signed or notarized?

Tags: security, notarization

This would be interesting in general but also helpful in diagnosing the frequent appearance of `MacOS error: -67062` in the Console.

Edit: in response to comments, the question is more specifically about trying to find out which processes are running that are NOT signed (or notarized).

Finding all running processes is trivial, but finding out whether their signed status seems to be tricky.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show all running processes on macOS/OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-show-all-running-processes-on-macos-os-x)

Comment: @jaume that question does not have answers showing if a process is from a signed app

Comment: @mmmmmm I'd say this question is about listing running processes, not about telling  between "signed" and "unsigned" processes apart. Or do you think the question is in fact: "is it possible to  ***only*** list running processes that are not signed or notarized"?

Comment: I read it as the latter - other wise not signed or notarized would not be mentioned.

Comment: @jaume I've edited the question to clarify, thanks for looking.

Comment: @mmmmmm - that is right, I'm after finding signed/notarized running processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to write a short script to gather this information.

Obtaining a [list of processes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220127) is possible with `ps` and code signatures of processes can be checked with `codesign`.

## codesign

The `codesign` command can be passed process identifiers, `pid`. To verify the signatures of two running processes call:

```
/usr/bin/codesign -d -vvvv 279 422
```

The flags are:

- `-d` for validation
- `-vvvv` to increased verbosity
- `279` the first process identifier to check
- `422` the second process identifier to check

Comment: Very helpful, thank you, a little shell script should manage this.